# CMake's execute_process find WSL's bash instead of MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The following:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E environment)
execute_process(COMMAND COMMAND bash -c pwd)
```

Prints:

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming
BUILD=Clean
BUILD_DIR=Windows-Release
CMAKE_DEFINES= -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64
CMAKE_EXE="cmake.exe"
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=GALA-T480
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
CONFIG=Release
configsetroot=C:\WINDOWS\ConfigSetRoot
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
EMBEDDED_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\myuser
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\GALA-T480
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
OneDrive=C:\Users\myuser\OneDrive
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\IncrediBuild;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc32\v2.15\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PLATFORM=Windows
PLATFORM_TOOLCHAIN=-T v140
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=8e0a
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SCRIPT_ERROR=0
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
TEMP=C:\Users\GALAHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\GALAHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=GALA-T480
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=GALA-T480
USERNAME=myuser
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\myuser
VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
vsconsoleoutput=1
windir=C:\WINDOWS
TERM_PROGRAM=vscode
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=1.36.1
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
/mnt/c/myrepo
```

Where the last line (the call for `pwd`) shows that the `bash` command goes to WSL instead of my MinGW installation. The strange thing is that under my `PATH` env variable (the first command output), the MinGW path is the first one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try putting the MinGW path as the last entry in your `Path` environment variable?

Comment: @squareskittles first entry